# Is there any way to grant a Notion Connection access to all pages in a workspace?

Tags: notion-api

I've begun digging into the Notion API, I created an integration and upon using their search endpoint I realized there were no results coming through. After digging a little deeper it seems their permissions system only allows you to give access to an integration on a per page basis instead of workspace wide.

As of now, is there any way to grant permissions for all pages within a workspace or is this on Notion's end?

```
const notionPages = async () => {
    const pageList = await nClient.search()
    console.log(pageList.results)
}

notionPages()
```

This comes back with zero results for a workspace with several pages UNLESS you go into the parent page and add the connection manually for every parent page.